# The reason for not having the communicationRange parameter in the case of the radio type of Ieee80211DimensionalRadio

Tags: omnet++, inet

When the radio is of Ieee80211DimensionalRadio radio type, why doesn't the INET 4.4 have a communicationRange parameter?
If not, please help how to set this parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is the same, why a WiFi card in a real computer does not have a setting where you can set how far the WiFi card can communicate. You do not set range in a real system. You set the transmission power and the effective range depends on that.

In short, you have to calculate the required power backwards from the range. Obviously, that is extremely complicated assuming that there are error correction, directional antennas, non-freespace propagation, etc..

The best you can do is to manually change the TX power and experiment to set it to a level suitable to you.

(additionally: There is no such thing as communication range in real world. There is always a probability that a packet is received for any distance. The question is, where you set your cutoff probability. This is always subjective).